# My notebook is shutting itself down randomly (not exactly)

Tags: 22.04, shutdown, laptop, battery, samsung

**Summary - current state:**

My Samsung ATIV Book 6 (model code: NP670Z5E-XD1BR), running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, is shutting down on its own "randomly" when under stress. More specifically, when turning on (it won't do it at all while not charging, it tries, displays "SAMSUNG" then turns off shortly after), playing games - notably more demanding ones, or during voice or video calls. When it's solely on battery, it turns off in a roughly minute while idle, less than a minute when doing most tasks, and almost instantly when doing any of the three things I listed above. When charging it varies a lot, sometimes it turns on with no problem, but it may take 2 or 3 tries; when I'm playing games, less than one hour, and, during calls, anything from a minute to hours until it's off again.

**Recent historic:**

About a year ago, my computer started turning off randomly. It wasn't an issue back then, because it wasn't very often and it wouldn't turn off while charging. But as time passed, it became worse and worse, and I found out that it was its charger and it was fixed. But the problem came back, again gradually, so I took the battery out and used it only on the power supply, and it got rid of the problem, but once again, I got the same issue 2 weeks later. Now, I installed the battery right back, kind of in despair, because I knew it wouldn't fix it, but it's getting really bad quickly.

**More possibly useful information:**

I recently cleaned my notebook, applied some new thermal paste and stress tested it, and it got 70°C at maximum stress give or take, so I don't believe the problem lies in temperature, but I probably need to do it again, since there is quite some time since I last tried this and the fans are making some weird noises (but it doesn't seem to affect its performance). Moreover, I tested its RAM (memtest), and it's working fine. Finally, drivers (should) be up to date.

**My conclusions:**

I'm zeroing in on some possibilities that include:

- Charging/battery circuits are messed up;
- BIOS problem;
- Problem with distro;
- Thermal sensor gone rogue (unlikely);
- For some reason, the machine thinks it has less power than it has (I'm not sure why yet)

I'm more inclined to say it's the first one, but I'll check the others first, maybe even some I didn't consider and you guys help me find out, and rule out if possible.

**Quick note:** I didn't want to bring it to technical assistance, because I don't want to spend money on a really old computer that will probably get completely unusable soon anyway, but I don't have much of a choice lately, since right now I can't buy a new one... But well, that's why I'm here! By the way, if it ends up being a hardware problem, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point me where I can find help. Lastly, sorry if off-topic or for bad English.

Comment: "*a really old computer that will probably get completely unusable soon anyway,*" Seems like you have reached that point. The symptoms your describe are most commonly associated with hardware faults.

Comment: hardware faults, and I'd wager that the laptop has had heat problems for a long time.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I think so too, but, as I said, this is all in desperation more than anything 